# .get method for hash in Crystal language

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, crystal-lang

I have this Python code:

```
# some_dic is a dictionary
value = some_dic.get(var_name, None)
```

How can I do the same in Crystal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map type called dictionary in Python is called Hash in Crystal.

Values with an explicit fallback value can be retrieved using the [`Hash#fetch`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.3.1/Hash.html#fetch%28key%2Cdefault%29-instance-method) method:

```
numbers = {"Alice" => "0123", "Bob" => "0124"}
puts numbers.fetch("Charlie", "0000")
```

So in your case

```
value = some_dic.fetch(var_name, nil)
```

If your default value should be `nil` then there's the handy [`Hash#[]?`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.3.1/Hash.html#%5B%5D%3F%28key%29-instance-method) method:

```
puts numbers["Charlie"]?
```

Read more about hashes in the language introduction: https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.3/syntax_and_semantics/literals/hash.html